# Derivation of equations of motion using vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

I was trying to draw the motion of a point mass given an initial position, velocity and constant acceleration. I figured that the change in position $\Delta \vec{r}$ over an interval $\Delta t$ would happen simultaneously with the change in velocity $\Delta \vec{v}$ (and the change in acceleration, but it's constant so $\Delta \vec{a} = 0$).

So I assumed that the following changes would happen:

- $\vec{v_1} = \vec{v_0} + \Delta \vec{v} = \vec{v_0} + \vec{a_0} \cdot \Delta t$
- $\vec{r_1} = \vec{r_0} + \Delta \vec{r} = \vec{r_0} + \vec{v_1} \cdot \Delta t$

But when you expand $\vec{v_1}$ in the second equation, you get:

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{r_1} &= \vec{r_0} + \vec{v_1} \cdot \Delta t \iff \\
\vec{r_1} &= \vec{r_0} + \left( \vec{v_0} + \vec{a_0} \cdot \Delta t \right) \cdot \Delta t \iff \\
\vec{r_1} &= \vec{r_0} + \vec{v_0} \cdot \Delta t + \vec{a_0} \cdot \Delta t^2
\end{align}
$$

Which is missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ for the acceleration part. What am I doing wrong? I tried to graph a visual image of what it looks like, but I can't seem to derive the $\frac{1}{2}$ from the vector representation alone.

[image: An xy graph with vectors representing the position, velocity and acceleration of a point mass]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In expression $$x = x_0 + \mathbb{E}[v]t \tag 1,$$

$\mathbb{E}[v]$ is expected speed value, or *average* speed vector, so

$$\begin{align}
 x &= x_0 + \frac {v_0+v_1}{2} t\\
   &=x_0+ \frac{v_0 + (v_0 + at)}{2}t\\
   &=x_0+ \frac{2v_0+at}{2}t \\
   &=x_0 + \left(v_0+\frac{at}{2}\right)t\\
   &=x_0 + v_0t+\frac{at^2}{2}
\end{align}
\tag 2$$

In general, if not specified otherwise in problem definition,- physics deals with expected values in most cases. I have depicted in your scheme average speed vector if that helps :
[image]

Comment: But what's the rationale behind using the average speed/velocity here? Intuitively it makes sense that the position and velocity don't just suddenly change at the end of the time interval, but that they instead smoothly change during the time interval, but I'm not sure how that necessarily gives you the average...

Comment: Well, for _instantaneous_ speed formula (1) does not apply, because instantaneous speed body can have only for a very short duration (it doesn't matter in what curve exactly it changes smoothly), hence for _instantaneous_ speed is only valid relation : $dx = v_i dt$. So if you want to know total displacement body has traveled - you need to integrate, because only calculus deals with elementary changes. And instantaneous speed involves elementary coordinate change in elementary time lapse. If in (1) speed is not an instantaneous speed, the only alternative is expected value. Hope that helps !

Answer (score 5):

The only thing missing is the fact that velocity is a variable and so is the position..
$\Delta{\vec{r}}$ should be written as ${d\vec{r}}$.
$${d\vec{r}}=\int\vec{v}_1dt$$
Then $\vec{r}_1$ turns out to be.
$$\vec{r}_1=\vec{r}_{0}+(\vec{v}_{0}\int{dt}+\vec{a}_{0}\int{tdt})$$
This can be integrated to get the required factor.

Alternative:-
Since we know that acceleration is constant we can substitute $\vec{v}_1$ as a constant value by using its average value. Which turns out to be.
$$\vec{v}_0+\frac{\vec{a}_0t}{2}$$

Comment: Yeah, I originally learned the calculus based derivation, which is why I noticed the missing factor, but I'm not sure why it's specifically the average velocity that yields the correct result.

Comment: @JansthcirlU IMO, it is much more related to fundamental theorem of calculus and how areas depends on boundary values. Areas of linear function in 2d space, requires us to find the area of trapezium, which consists average term.